# Using opencv in Win32 application for image show

Tags: user-interface, opencv

Is it possible to output images so that they all will be inside a single window?
Before, I used to output data using only opencv functions:

```
cvNamedWindow("Image 1");
cvShowImage("Image 1", img);
```

So I change image, then call: `cvShowImage` function and so on.
But If I want to look at more than one image, then every new image needs its own window to be shown there And what I want is to put every such an output opencv's window inside one big main window.

Is it possible to do it? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to construct a new image and place each `img` into it. I don't think there's a builtin function like MATLAB's `subplot`. I recommend using the ROI functions to quickly copy an image into a region-of-interest (ROI) of the big image (which holds the others).

Answer (score 0):

You can show as many images as you want on a single window using hconcat function.
Let us suppose your original image was

```
Mat frame;
```

Now clone or make a copy of this image using

```
Mat frame1 = frame.clone();//or
Mat frame2;
frame.copyTo(frame1);
```

Now let us suppose your output images are

```
Mat img1,img2,img3,img4;
```

Now if you want to show images horizontally, use

```
hconcat(img1,img2,frame1)//hconcat(input_image1,input_image2,destination_image);
```

And if you want to show images vertically, use

```
frame2.push_back(img1);//main_image.push_back(image_to_be_shown_below);
```

This process processess images one at a time, so if you want to show 4 images side by side, you have to call this function 4 times as in

```
hconcat(img1,img2,frame1);
hconcat(frame1,img3,frame1);
hconcat(frame1,img4,frame1);
imshow("Final Image",frame1);
```

NOTE:
Clone process is done because the images have to be of same size.

Enjoy...